# Blackberry Webworks Input focus issue

Tags: blackberry-webworks

I've found that it takes two clicks to select an input box (or click an input button).

To demonstrate this, I've made a video -

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ejG2pXIB8ds

The first click highlights the input box and gives it a blue border. The second click enters it.

To move from that to another input box (or to click a button) again takes multiple clicks, one "wasted" to highlight, one to enter.

This behaviour is unacceptable for my app - and leaves the user clicking the screen repeatedly, like it's faulty.

The first click (the one that highlights) doesn't trigger click, mousedown or focus in jquery, so I can't even bodge it.

I'm running SDK  - 2.3.1.5 - on OS7.

Does anyone know a way around this - on OS6, 1 click = focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it.

Seems BB have applied their own touch events, which is causing this click non-focus issue:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   fixClicks();
});

function fixClicks(){
    if (blackberry.system.softwareVersion.substring(-1,1) == "7"){
        window.addEventListener("touchend", function(e){
           if (e.target.tagName == "INPUT"){
                switch(e.target.type){
                case "button":
                  e.preventDefault();
                  $(e.target).trigger("click");
                  break;
                case "input":
                  $(e.target).focus();
                  break;
                case "radio":
                  $(e.target).focus();
                  break;
                default:
                  $(e.target).focus();
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
```